# Dragging a Chrome tab out, then presses Shift cancels the drag and the tab goes back to the windows

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome

I use the PowerToys feature FancyZones to drag windows to predefines areas (it works quite well!). I drag a window, press Shift and then drop the window in the wanted zone.

So my problem is, that I use the Shift key often when dragging a window, but if I drag a tab out of a Google Chrome window, tab Shift to activate FancyZones, the tab goes right back into the Chrome window. I now have to drag it out again, drop it, then drag the tab/window again, now with Shift, to put it in a FancyZone.

I'd like the Shift key to be ignored by Chrome when dragging a tab out of a Chrome window.

My problem is not related to FancyZones, the same happens if I disable FancyZone.

Any ideas?

- Google Chrome version 94.0.4606.71 (Official Build) (64-bit)
- Windows 10 version 21H1 (OS Build 19043.1237)
- PowerToys version (though unrelated) v0.47.0

.

**Update 25-10-2021**: I have now reported this to Google as an issue via the Chrome Help menu and hope they will make the change.

Comment: I have a feeling that dragging a window out of Chrome is a function of Chrome, and not the OS. Dragging a tab out of the active window is handled by Chrome to request a new window with the tab as the content. In this case, PowerToys cannot be used on the window until it has been created.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Yes, this is not a PowerToys-problem and yes, I agree that it is Chrome that is responsible here.